# Better way than flat_map to iterate over data structure

Tags: ruby

I have an array of Users, and each User responds to a method called houses that return all the houses of the users. I want to have an array of hashes with users name and houses color name, so here is what I have:

```
[user1, user2, user3].flat_map do |user|
  user.houses.map do |house|
    create_user_house(user, house)
  end
end

def create_user_house(user, house)
  {name: user.name, house: find_color(house)}
end
```

Is there any better way of doing this? I have a feeling that using `flat_map` might be overkill in this situation

EXAMPLE:

Say I have two users:

```
user_1 which name is 'John'
user_1 has two houses: house_1 and house_2
user_2 which name is 'Steve'
user_2 has one house: house_3
```

The expected result should be:

```
[{name: 'John', house_color: find_color(house1)}, {name: 'John', house_color: find_color(house2)}, {name: 'Steve', house_color: find_color(house3)}]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the final data structure you want, using dummy data?

Comment: But do you actually want that or: `[{name: 'John', house_color: "red"},...` as the final output?

Comment: You are "denormalizing" or "flattening" the data so flat_map seems to me the right thing to use.

Comment: Yeah, `#flat_map` is the most concise way to do what you want to do.

Comment: You really should have provided some sample data. It would not be difficult, as you see from my answer.  If you want to incorporate that example (possibly modified) into your question, I would delete it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have some data to work with:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :houses
  def initialize name, houses
    @name   = name
    @houses = houses
  end
end

wilma = User.new 'Wilma', [:bungalow, :cottage]
hank  = User.new 'Hank',  [:cape_cod, :bungalow]
oaf   = User.new 'Oaf',   [:shed,     :cottage]

def find_color(h)
  case h
  when :bungalow then :yellow
  when :cottage  then :blue
  when :cape_cod then :white
  when :shed     then :black
  end
end
```

You approach is fine, but I'm not sure you need the separate method. Without it, it's:

```
[wilma, hank, oaf].flat_map do |user|
  user.houses.map { |h| { name: user.name, house_color: find_color(h) } }
end
  #=> [{:name=>"Wilma", :house_color=>:yellow},
  #    {:name=>"Wilma", :house_color=>:blue},
  #    {:name=>"Hank",  :house_color=>:white},
  #    {:name=>"Hank",  :house_color=>:yellow},
  #    {:name=>"Oaf",   :house_color=>:black},
  #    {:name=>"Oaf",   :house_color=>:blue}]
```

I think `flat_map` is quite appropriate here.

You could write it many other ways, of course, one being:

```
[wilma, hank, oaf].each_with_object([]) do |user, a|
  user.houses.each { |h| a << { name: user.name, house_color: find_color(h) } }
end
```

Comment: Nopes, sorry. I want repeated hashes for each house that a user owns. I have edited my question with an example. Thanks

Comment: Instead of ```{ name: user.name, house_color: h.map { |h| find_color(h) } }``` I just need ```{ name: user.name, house_color: find_color(h) }``` which was what I used in my question... Thanks

Comment: Cary, his `create_user_house` returns the hash so inside the nested `map` it would just call the `create_user_house` method.

Comment: @Beartech, yes, thanks. It was all made clear when I added some data.